# My boss deactivated the "Running User" who created the President's Dashboard which then disappeared

Tags: permissions, dashboard, reports-folder

As stated in the title, in Classic, my boss deactivated a "Running User" who created the President's Dashboard which then disappeared.  The deactivation was performed because that person is no longer with the company and my boss needed to free up a seat to grant me administrative privileges and place me as the new Running User on all Dashboards and to allow me the abiity to run the Lightning Compatibility Test.

I attempted to reactivate the former employees account; so as to allow the missing Dashboard to repopulate.  However, because there are no remaining seats, I only got a red flag error message telling me there's no room at the inn.

The data from the vanished Dashboard is still searchable in our Org as well as the Dashboard record (although empty).

What is the easiest method of reconstructing the President's dashboard?

Comment: the dashboard would still be in a public dashboard and you, as the system admin, should be able to make either you or the "president' as the running user.  This is a good lesson in making sure that critical recurring jobs be assigned to a headless user seat that by convention, you don't deactivate.

Comment: Cropredy, that the information is still in the Org is understood.  But does that mean the fastest, easiest, and only solution is to rebuild the Dashboard manually,  or can it be recovered by reactivating the former employee as the Running User?  I do like the idea of a headless user.  Does that require us to purchase another seat or commandeer one of our current user's seats for that purpose?

Comment: The dashboard still exists because the President was viewing it and did not create it

Comment: Thank you cropredy.  That makes all the sense in the world.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, if the dearly-departed colleague set up a dashboard that the "President" can see, then the dashboard must exist in a public dashboard folder.

Since you are a system admin, you too have access to this public folder and can change the running user to:

- yourself
- the "President"
- a headless user (e.g. `sfdc-automated-stuff@mycompany.com`) - best option as it means that when you leave or the "president" leaves, the dashboard is still available to be viewed by anyone with permissions to that dashboard folder.